# How to get the number of unread messages for user from synapse server via API

Tags: matrix-synapse

How can the number of unread messages (or events) for a specific user be retrieved from a matrix synapse server via API?
Via the synapse admin or the matrix client-server API.

Events seem to be a complex topic.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

1. https://spec.matrix.org/v1.1/client-server-api/#get_matrixclientv3notifications returns only unread notifications
2. https://spec.matrix.org/v1.1/client-server-api/#get_matrixclientv3sync returns the number of unread notifications for each room the user is a member: "org.matrix.msc2654.unread_count": 0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.